# Set boolean value to Eval() variable in AS2

Tags: flash, eval, actionscript-2

I have set a boolean value:

```
austria_clicked = false;
```

I want to access this value and change it through eval function, because the country name will change in "for" cycle.

```
eval( country + "_clicked") = true;
```

But this isn't working, it's giving me this compiling error:

```
Symbol=Interactive map, layer=actions_mouse, frame=1, Line 63   Left side of assignment operator must be variable or property.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Array access operator `[]`:

```
 this[country + "_clicked"] = true;
```

There are some other alternatives as well (old method from Flash 4 apparently):

```
 set(country + "_clicked", true);
```

Or, don't use `eval()` on the left side of the assignment operator (`=`), this was probably added for security reasons:

```
 var foo = eval(country + "_clicked"); // eval() is used on the right!
 foo = true;
```

I've never programmed in AS2 (only AS3), so hope this helps. It's explained very nicely in this [blog post](http://www.quip.net/blog/2006/flash/actionscript-20/reference-objects-dynamically).

Comment: set(country + "_clicked", true);  <---- worked like a charm, thank you so much for insight and blog post :)